# Sweet potatoes: to cook or not to cook?

Tags: food-safety, dehydrating, sweet-potatoes

I would like to dehydrate some sweet potatoes. [Here](http://www.vegetariantimes.com/recipe/rosemary-sweet-potato-chips/) I found a recipe for dehydrating fresh sweet potatoes in low temperatures without cooking them first. But [here](http://vegpeace.org/rawfoodtoxins.html) they say that fresh sweet potatoes contain toxins and should not be eaten without cooking. So what is the truth? Is it safe to eat dehydrated sweet potatoes that were not cooked first?

Comment: The act of dehydrating will denature _some_ things in the sweet potatoes (in many ways dehydrating/freezing will have the same effect as cooking). I can't say if the enzyme you're worried about will be destroyed (hence this not being an answer).

Comment: *enzymes rather toxins

Comment: How can one ever eat raw sweet potato? Usually pressure-cook it, cook in the steam for consumption. I don't get it, why do you opt to dehydrate?

Comment: @bonCodigo: usually, raw vegetables contain some enzymes and nutrients that are destroyed by cooking. So my default option is to eat raw. However, there are some vegetables that must not be eaten raw because they contain toxins. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer cooking them first. Sun-dried sweet potatoes do exist in some parts of Asia as a snack. They are chewy chunks rather than crispy slices as shown in your link. There are also freeze-dried ones around these days. Anti-nutrition contents are not overwhelming in sweet potatoes to my knowledge. So, uncooked should be fine. I think you will get better texture and avoid browning by cooking them first.